# MacOS Warning on Terminal Startup: "Warning: No available formula with the name "pure#". Did you mean pure?"

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh

I recently tried to install a zsh prompt called pure, where I followed the instructions listed on its Github page

https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure

I set my ZSH_THEME = "", ran `brew install pure`, then ran

```
# .zshrc
autoload -U promptinit; promptinit
prompt pure
```

As said in the Github Page. This however did not change the terminal theme and now whenever I start my terminal, I get this annoying warning message

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "pure#". Did you mean pure?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
pure ✔                             pure-ftpd                          purescript                         purescript-language-server

To install pure ✔, run:
  brew install pure ✔

==> Casks
pure-writer                                    purei-play                                     purevpn

To install pure-writer, run:
  brew install --cask pure-writer
```

I really don't even care about the prompt anymore and more just want to get rid of this warning message.

I tried running `brew uninstall pure` and that didn't get rid of the error message. I also ran `npm install --global pure-prompt` to see if that would do anything. Running `brew doctor` also just said `Your system is ready to brew.`

How can I get rid of the message? It looks like it's trying to install the wrong package? No clue :(

Comment: The message is triggered by one of your startup files (or any file included/called form there), probably in a line which somehow calls `brew`. You will need to look in all of them (or restore them from a backup from before installing `pure`).

Comment: How can I find these startup files or restore them to a backup? I only installed pure yesterday so I dont think I'd have a backup

Comment: `man zsh`, "FILES" section at the end. By default, `$DOTDIR` is your home directory.

Comment: Hmm I looked through all of them and it looks like the only file that runs a script is `~./zprofile` which just runs `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

Could this be it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration.
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1808960/macos-warning-on-terminal-startup-warning-no-available-formula-with-the-name

Comment: Doesn‘t hurt to try, does it?

Comment: It looks like the error comes from the terminal downloading this url `https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json`, how did pure get in this?

Comment: What is causing the download here, and why do you think this is the issue? Remember, we can't see what you are doing or what is on your screen, so unless you share details we simple can't help a lot. Also, if your Homebrew installation seems to be the issue, run `brew doctor` and fix any issues found.

Comment: Not sure, it seems to happen whenever I launch the terminal. Running `brew doctor` yields nothing

Comment: _How can I find these startup files_ : By reading `man zsh`, and there the section titled _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_. It shows which files zsh automatically processes. Alternatively, start your new shell with `zsh -x ...`. This also shows which files are processed.

Comment: Found the issue, the pure installation added a line to my ~/.zshrc file without commenting it. Thanks for all your help guys